# Force table column width to always be fixed regardless of increasing number of column?

Tags: html, css

I have a table row of 3 columns. As I am filling the table data based on some API calls, I am getting more columns. So whenever column number increases the width of the row increases. 
[image: my html table]

> How can I make the width of the table fixed?

Comment: have you tried `table-layout: fixed` in your CSS?

Comment: <table style='width: 200 %; table-layout: fixed; page-break-before:always;' class='table table-bordered'>

Comment: Do you mind providing your html, and the css for the styling on the table? [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I am making inner HTML with string from my code. I mean I am making HTML table with string variable. So It will be difficult to understand. I just want if there any trick available to make the table width same always.

Comment: In a table, you **must ensure** that each table row has exactly the same number of cells **at all times.** Also, a table can never be less wide than the sum of its columns' widths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fist of all: your columns should have content of the same category, so "land size" should be always on the same column, and the first rows (9.1 to 9.6) should be on another table.

So you can define the table width in CSS and should dynamically add new columns (on the same position) for each row whenever column number increases or increase the "colspan" attribute for the last cells of each row.

My suggestion is table #3:

```css
/* CSS */
table { width:100% }
th { background:#000; color:#fff }
td { border:1px solid; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan='3'>Group: Socio-Economic Profile</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>9.1</td>
    <td>Name of the interviewer:</td>
    <td>Sharif</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>9.1</td>
    <td>AP number:</td>
    <td>End</td>
  </tr>
</table>


<br><br>Option 1 - Multiple tables (one for each group)
<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan='5'>Group: Household Land</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Present price</th>
    <th>Size</th>
    <th>Whou used the land?</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Inerithance</td>
    <td>150,000</td>
    <td>16.0</td>
    <td>Others</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan='6'>Group: Agricultural Land</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Present price</th>
    <th>Size</th>
    <th>Whou used the land?</th>
    <th>Do you have any agricultural land?</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Inerithance</td>
    <td>70,000</td>
    <td>58.0</td>
    <td>Own</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
  </tr>
</table>


<br><br>Option 2 - Single table, but repeat questions 
<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan='6'>Group: Household Land</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Present price</th>
    <th>Size</th>
    <th colspan='2'>Whou used the land?</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Inerithance</td>
    <td>150,000</td>
    <td>16.0</td>
    <td colspan='2'>Others</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan='6'>Group: Agricultural Land</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Present price</th>
    <th>Size</th>
    <th>Whou used the land?</th>
    <th>Do you have any agricultural land?</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Inerithance</td>
    <td>70,000</td>
    <td>58.0</td>
    <td>Own</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>



Option 3 - Same table, groups by columns
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Group</th>
    <th>Land Title</th>
    <th>Land Present price</th>
    <th>Land Size</th>
    <th>Whou used the land?</th>
    <th>Do you have any land (of your group)?</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Household land</td>
    <td>Inerithance</td>
    <td>150,000</td>
    <td>16.0</td>
    <td>Others</td>
    <td>---</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Agricultural land</td>
    <td>Inerithance</td>
    <td>70,000</td>
    <td>58.0</td>
    <td>Own</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```